# jquery selection on a select list

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a question about jquery selection. I want to target a select list, when you select "Dr" from the select list, then a div below should be hidden.

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/leisureman/pen/qPLvEa)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var num = Dr;
$("div#myselect select.select option").each(function(){
    if($(this).selected()==num){
        $(".test1").hide();   
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `Dr` should be a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's *a lot* wrong here.  At a quick glance:

1. `Dr` is a syntax error. Strings should be wrapped in quotes.
2. You're checking for the selected value once when the page loads, without giving the user a chance to actually select anything.
3. You're looking for a `select` with `class="select"`, which doesn't exist in your HTML.
4. You're also looking for a `div` with `id="myselect"`, which also doesn't exist in your HTML.
5. There is no .selected() function.

I *suspect* you meant something more like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 'Dr';
    $("select").change(function(){
        if($(this).find('option:selected').text()==num){
            $(".test1").hide();   
        }
    });
});
```

Note the changes:

1. Wrapped `Dr` in quotes because it's a string.
2. Create a `change` event handler instead of just directly checking the current state of the HTML.  This event handler will be invoked any time the target element "changes".  (Has its value modified by the user.)
3. Replaced the selector with just `select` to target the `<select>` form element on the page.  If there are more `<select>` elements in your target code then you could also use that `id` you have, or identify your target `<select>` element(s) in any of a variety of ways.
4. Upon invoking the `change` event, the code looks for the selected option within the `<select>` and checks the *text* of that option.  (Since the `value` is a number and not the string `'Dr'`.)

I've forked your [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxrGVe) here to demonstrate.

Additionally, if you want to *re-show* the element when another option is selected, you'd add an `else` block:

```
if($(this).find('option:selected').text()==num){
    $(".test1").hide();   
} else {
    $(".test1").show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am learning the difference between targeting value vs text. I created another pen here that targets the value. https://codepen.io/leisureman/pen/vevMgP

Answer (score 1):

A few errors. First you need to enclose strings in quotes. Next you want to check the select list when someone makes a change, so you don't want to use `.each()` but rather the `.change()` event. Then you don't want to check the value since that's numeric, so use `.text()` or `.html()` to get the content of the selected option instead of `.val()`.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num = 'Dr';
  $("#myselect").change(function() {
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == num) {
      $(".test1").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>

<div class="test1">test1</div>
```